# Using matlotlib: why do imshow and contourf not plot together? (contourf "overrides" imshow)

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, imshow, contourf

I am trying to plot some meteorological data onto a map and I would like to add an image of a plane using imshow. Plotting i) the trajectory, ii) some contour-data and iii) the image, works fine. But as soon as I add a contourf-plot (see below) the image dissapears!

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import cartopy.crs as crs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

def plot_test():
    #DEFINE DATA

    x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0,90,100),np.linspace(0,90,100))
    z = x**3 + y**3
    
    #BEGIN FIGURE (IN THIS CASE A MAP, IM PLOTTING METEOROLOGICAL DATA)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize = (6,6))
    ax1 = plt.axes(projection=crs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=0))
    ax1.set_extent([0,90,0,90], crs=crs.PlateCarree())
    ax1.coastlines(resolution='auto', color='k')
    
    #EXAMPLE DATA PLOTTED AS CONTOURF
    v_max = int(z.max())    
    v_min = int(z.min())
    qcs = ax1.contourf(x, y, z, cmap = "Blues", vmin = v_min, vmax = v_max)
    sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap="Blues",norm=qcs.norm)
    sm._A = []
    cbar = plt.colorbar(sm, ax=ax1,orientation="vertical")
    cbar.ax.set_ylabel("some contourf data", rotation=90, fontsize = 15)
            
    #PLOT IMAGE OF A PLANE (THIS IS NOT SHOWING UP ON THE PLOT!)
    x0 = 50
    y0 = 40
    img=plt.imread("plane2.png")
    ax1.imshow(img,extent=[x0,x0 - 10, y0, y0-10], label = "plane")

    plt.show()
```

without contourf (code from above with lines 14-20 commented out):

[image]

with contourf:

[image: with contourf]

Comment: Did you try to change the z-order? `ax1.imshow(img, ...., zorder=3)`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the code provided on Ubuntu/matplotlib 3.5.1 . However, the code is not the one producing your second image; `alpha = 0.4` or similar is not specified to generate a semitransparent contour plot.

Comment: Thank you JohanC! Im new here so I don't know if I can reply to your comment directly but I posted your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you 1000 times @JohanC (see comments). I simply had to place the z-order:

```
ax1.imshow(img, ...., zorder=3)
```

which made the plane show up!